# Drupal: Remove tag-text from articles

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tags, drupal-modules

Suddenly, drupal 7 shows tags under my articles. How do I remove this?

See this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields     delete   or

admin/structure/types/manage/article/display   make hidden  this field

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually was in these options before but didn't hide it, thought it would just affect the "Add content".